# HTML5 videos don't autoplay with tippy js

Tags: javascript, html, video, tippyjs

I use tippy.js and when I add a `<video loop muted playsinline autoplay>` inside a tooltip using `allowHTML: true`, the video won't autoplay on chrome. It works on firefox and safari though.

How can I achieve this?

Here is my js:

```
const modal = card.querySelector('.modal'),
            modalContent = modal.innerHTML`

      tippy('.card', {
        content: modalContent,
        allowHTML: true,
        interactive: true,
        animation: 'shift-away',
        followCursor: true,
        arrow: false
      });
```

And here is my html:

```
<div class="modal">
   <div>
      <video loop muted playsinline autoplay>
        <source src="http://localhost:8888/artifacts/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/Artifacts-Landing.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
      </video>
   </div>
</div>
```

I tried to add

```
card.querySelector('video').play()
```

but it doesn't work eather.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help,

Comment: "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive, is there some kind of error or what exactly

Comment: @Joshua I get no error, only the video stays paused on first frame. Could it be linked to the tooltip visibility status maybe? Since the tooltip is hidden first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed strange that a muted video would not autoplay. You can use `setTimeout` and then trigger `play()` using the `onShow()` event. For some reason `onShown()` doesn't ever fire for me.

Here's a working snippet:

```js
const modal = document.querySelector('.modal'),
  modalContent = modal.innerHTML;

tippy('.card', {
  content: modalContent,
  allowHTML: true,
  interactive: true,
  animation: 'shift-away',
  followCursor: true,
  arrow: false,
  onShow(instance) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      let video = instance.popper.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
      video.currentTime = 0; //start from begining
      video.play();
    }, 1);

  },
});
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
}

video {
  width: 40vw;
}

.card {
  padding-top: 10vh;
}

h1{
  display:inline;
  margin:1em;
}
```

```html
<!-- Production -->
<h1 class="card">CARD 1</h1>
<h1 class="card">CARD 2</h1>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@6"></script>

<div class="modal">
  <div>
    <video loop muted playsinline autoplay>
        <source src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/6/6c/%22Movbild-fizika%22_falo_en_Big_Buck_Bunny.webm/%22Movbild-fizika%22_falo_en_Big_Buck_Bunny.webm.720p.vp9.webm" type="video/mp4"> 
      </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Miro! It's working perfectly, but it breaks when there are more than one video in the dom. I tried to replace `document.getElementsByTagName('video')[1].play();` with `card.getElementsByTagName('video')[1].play();` but i get a _cannot read properties of undefine_.
If I try `card.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].play();` I get no errors, but autoplay isn't triggered. Strange cause if I console.log `card.getElementsByTagName('video')[0]`, I get the dom element in the console

Comment: Try with `instance.popper.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].play()` That should target the video inside the current modal/tooltip. Edited the example above